Regarding the characteristic of field extension of residue fields
We assume that $L/K$ is a Galois extension of number fields and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a nonzero prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
A prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$ lies over $\mathfrak{p}$ if $\mathfrak{q}$ contains $\mathfrak{p}$.
Let $k$ be the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ and $l$ the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{q}$ where $\mathfrak{q}$ denotes an prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $l/k$ is an extension of finite fields of characteristic $p$, where $p\mathbb{Z}=\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}.$
I have difficulty understanding the characteristic of $l/k$ is $p$. A detailed explanation or an example is highly appreciated.

In the future, please use markdown to format non-mathematical text instead of MathJax.

@KReiser Thank you, get it.

The field $k$ (and similarly $l$) is of characteristic $p$ for the simplest reason: $p \in \mathfrak{p}$, so $p$ is zero in $k = \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$.
If you need a concrete example, you could take a first look at $K=\Bbb Q$, $\mathfrak{p}=p \Bbb Z$, in this case $\mathcal{O}_K = \Bbb Z$, and hence $k = \Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z$. If you need something more involved, you could try to work out by hand the following examples (for which you need to argue first what $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $p$ are):

$L = \Bbb Q(i)$, $\mathfrak{q} = (1+i)$,
$L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathfrak{q} = (\sqrt{2})$,
more generally, if you know some basics of quadratic extensions, let $d \in \Bbb Z$ be squarefree, let $L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ appropriately chosen (you need to distinguish cases),
Cyclotomic extensions if you know some basics about them.

Notice that the first example is a special case of the last two, which can help you ensure you understood everything right. I would say these are the basic examples to play with to build intuition on new concepts in number theory. There is not a lot of other cases which can be computed explicitely.
